# Attribute selector in material UI makeStyles

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, makestyles

I'm working on a react project and I want to apply CSS based on the position attribute of material UI's Popper element. However, I couldn't find any example which used attribute selector for material UI. I tried the following approach, but it didn't work.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles ({
 popper: {
 '&[x-placement*="right"]':{
   // JSS  
  },
  '&[x-placement*="left"]': {
    // JSS 
  }
 }
})
```

I tried the above approach using styled components API and it worked. However, does this work in makeStyles or useStyles

Comment: Yes, this does work beautifully with makestyles.